# adding a php variable to a jquery url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

please friends i want to run a javascript code to load a php page which is based on $_GET variable. here is the actual page:

```
    <?php
$online = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM (SELECT user as user FROM online) as a INNER JOIN
(SELECT one as f1 FROM friends WHERE two='$my_id'
UNION SELECT two as f2 FROM friends WHERE one='$my_id') as b
ON a.user = b.f1");
while($query = mysqli_fetch_array($online)){
    $active = $query['user'];
    $first = getuser($active, 'first');
    $nick = getuser($active, 'nick');
    $last = getuser($active, 'last');
?>
<?php
echo "<font class='driver'>$first $nick $last</font>";
<div style="width:100%;height:82%;overflow-x:no;overflow-y:auto;" id="show">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#show').load('active_chat.php')
            }, 2000);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

so i want this line `$('#show').load('active_chat.php')` to look something like this `$('#show').load('active_chat.php?id=$active')` so that it will display information entered by only a user for each `$active`, here is the active_chat.php;

```
    <?php

include 'connect.php';

include 'functions.php';

$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$user = $_GET['id'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM all_msgs WHERE (my_id='$my_id' AND user_id='$user') OR (my_id='$user' AND user_id='$my_id') AND delet !='$my_id' ORDER BY id DESC");
while($sql = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $msg = $sql['msg_body'];
    $sender = $sql['my_id'];
    $first = getuser($sender, 'first');
    $nick = getuser($sender, 'nick');
    $last = getuser($sender, 'last');
    $photo = getuser($sender, 'photo'); 

    echo $first." ".$nick." ".$last;
    }    ?>
```

Comment: FYI: The `<font>` tag was deprecated and removed many years ago ?

Comment: `$('#show').load('active_chat.php?id=<?php echo $active; ?>')`? Also, I don't see a closing `}` for your `while($query = mysqli_fetch_array($online)){`. Are you repeating the `<script>` block in every loop?

Comment: yes i am reapeating it in every loop